# How can I maintain user credentials (django server) in a way that bypasses the login page on an iOS app even after turning the phone off?

Tags: ios, django, ios7, oauth-2.0, django-authentication

I've been told to use Oauth2.0, but I don't understand what I am to do with it on either side.
I would specifically like to achieve the persistent login that Facebook and Twitter maintain in their respective iOS apps.

PLEASE give me a specific answer (and hopefully an example too!) 
I know that this may be achieve with Oauth2.0, but I have been unable to find an example as to how (even after extensive research- if I could find the answer I wouldn't be asking the question here.)

Thank you in advance!

-John

Comment: Have you tried to use OAuth 2.0? What HAVE you tried? If you really had done "extensive research" it seems like you would have found something to try out.

Comment: I can't find anything showing me exactly how to use OAuth. The best tutorial I've found shows OAuth used WITH tastypie. I don't want to use OAuth 2.0 with anything other than django; nothing else

Comment: A google search of "OAuth 2.0 django" found several hits that seemed promising. I recommend you go through whatever OAuth tutorials you can find to get the basics of the concepts, and then look at some of the OAuth/django solutions to see how people are applying OAuth with Django.